# Increase output power of simple class AB audio amplifier

Tags: bjt, power-amplifier

How could one increase the output power from a class AB amplifier circuit like this one? I wish to increase the output power to around 2W.

[image: Class AB Amplifier schematic]

The above picture is simulated with a 200mV amplitude, 5kHz sine wave input which is amplified to 4V amplitude through op-amp U1A.

Also, how does the size of the resistors R7 and R8 impact the amount of current the transistors Q1 and Q2 can push/pull?

Comment: What is the desired output power? It matters.

Comment: Around 2W - I edited the question to include this information.

Comment: \$\sqrt{2\cdot 8\:\Omega\cdot 2\:\text{W}}\approx \pm 5.7\:\text{V}\$. You'll need to include another \$2\cdot 1.5\:\text{V}=3\:\text{V}\$ on top of that. So this means about \$15\:\text{V}\$ total for the power supply rail. Not \$12\:\text{V}\$.

Comment: I'd probably go for \$16\:\text{V}\$ to \$18\:\text{V}\$ as my rail. Also, the entire topology is wrong.

Comment: oh yes, yet another circuit copied from a magazine by another magazine, scanned by some guy in the 90s, then copied from a newsgroup to a website, where the last bit of explanation was lost, then stolen by another website, and then even that was lost. Seriously, none of this circuit makes much sense in 2018 (even **if** it made sense architectually in the original); starting with the *terrible* choice of transistors. One would increase the output power of this amplifier by ... replacing it with one where the Opamp IC makes space for an audio amplifier IC and all the rest is dropped.

Comment: Look for 3W BTL amplifier ICs. They are all over the place. Plenty of margin and they run off of \$9\:\text{V}\$. A lot of them have very simple volume controls, too.

Comment: Use a 4 ohm speaker.

Comment: You can use LM386s in a bridged configuration. That would be a simple cheap way to increase your power without having to read how these things work. @Andyaka's suggestion is probably the easiest way to double your power though.